# Something seems to be wrong with this *seltsame* question on the Careers page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

[image: Snapshot]

Hi, looking at the right side and seeing the prominent question in the blue box, I would say something is...somehow...*falsch*. *Irgendwie verkehrt*, if you know what I mean.

Could you take a look ? *Danke*.

Comment: Good one. Will be repariert soon!

Comment: Always at your service !

Comment: The image is definitively missing a roter handgemalter Kreis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix is being deployed now. Thanks much!